# Ember run.debounce not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to get debounce working on our app.  This works on a local test app, and on the twiddle example, but not the one I am working on. https://ember-twiddle.com/6470734cd3111fd3049f3e900aa676c4?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.application.hbs

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: "Debounce",
  it: false,
  actions: {
        changeIt() {
            this.toggleProperty('it');
        }
  },
  logIt() {
    console.log('logging it');
    console.log(this.get('it'));
    },
  observeIt: Ember.observer('it', function() {
   console.log('will debounce');
   Ember.run.debounce(this, 'logIt', 5000, false);
  }),

});
```

The issue is that 'logIt' is always fired immediately, and will keep firing with no delay or throttling.  Since it works in one app an not another, is it possible a plugin is messing it up?  I am clueless.

Using Ember version 2.4.3

Comment: Is this the code that isn't working on your app?  If so, which version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Maybe try to specify the `immediate` parameter? `Ember.run.debounce(this, 'logIt', 5000, false);` Also what ember version has this app?

Comment: Specified immediate as false, still not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ember.run.debounce(this, 'logIt', 5000, false);
```

to

```
Ember.run.debounce(this, this.logIt, 5000, false);
```

Comment: How does this fix the problem?

Comment: @torazaburo - 'logIt' is a string, while this.logIt is an ember object.